# How do I get the value for a key from a const ref?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

Why is that I cannot get the value of a key, in a const ref unordered_map that I have passed into the function, but I can for a local unordered_map ?

```
GameObject(const std::unordered_map<int,std::unordered_map<int,int>>& objectParameters){
        if (objectParameters.find(CAPABILITY_TYPE_SPECIE)!=objectParameters.end()) {

 //Following line gives an error:
    auto map2 = objectParameters[CAPABILITY_TYPE_SPECIE];         

//Following line works just fine
            std::unordered_map<int,std::unordered_map<int,int>> objectParameters2;
            auto map = objectParameters2[CAPABILITY_TYPE_SPECIE];

        }
```

Why can't I get the value from objectParameters ?
The error that the compiler complains is:

> No viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const
>   std::unordered_map >'

EDIT: Removing "const" from the type seems to make the error go away. Why is that ?

Comment: map::at() is the member function you need. `auto map2 = objectParameters.at(CAPABILITY_TYPE_SPECIE);`. Please look at Killzone Kid's answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`operator[]` is a non-const member function and can't be called on an object you have by a const reference. It can't be a const member, since it's specified to **insert an item** if the key isn't in the map. And it just so happens you don't even need to use it.

You employ `find()` and then just discard the result, why? It gets an iterator to the item if that item exists. So don't discard it, use it.

```
auto item = objectParameters.find(CAPABILITY_TYPE_SPECIE);
if (item != objectParameters.end()) {
     auto map2 = item->second;
```

Though if you want `map2` to be the same one that is already in `map1`, the above doesn't do that either. Since `auto map2` is a copy of `item->second`. To modify the item in `map1`, we'd need to make `map2` a reference:

```
auto item = objectParameters.find(CAPABILITY_TYPE_SPECIE);
if (item != objectParameters.end()) {
     auto& map2 = item->second;
```

Regarding your edit, removing const to "fix" such errors is the wrong thing to do. Const correctness is important, and when you do such a "fix" it can introduce subtle bugs into your code. Because now things that shouldn't change may start changing unexpectedly.

Comment: The how do I pass an unordered_map to a constructor and prevent the constructor from modifying it ? It seems like const is the way, unless I pass by value...

Comment: @KaizerSozay - You pass by a const referece, and don't call non-const member functions. There's nothing more to it.

Comment: But isn't that what I've done ? I passed by const reference... can you explain please ? I don't understand...

Comment: @KaizerSozay - You passed a const reference. And like I told you, `operator[]` is not a const member function, so you can't call it with a const reference.

Comment: Ok - now i think i understand - I use const reference, but I don't use []. Instead I use the result from find - ie. item->second.

Comment: @KaizerSozay - Exactly. You can see a complete reference for [unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). It specifies all member functions, so you should be able to find the ones you need to effectively work with both const and non-const objects.

Answer (score 2):

> Why can't I get the value from objectParameters ?

Because when accessing map element with operator [] and key doesn't exist it will be created. Obviously compiler cannot do this if map is `const`.

You could try using `.at()` as it has `const` overload http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at

Comment: What if I don't want the constructor to be able to modify the map ?

Comment: @Kaizer Sozay: map::at() is what you are looking for. But you should wrap it in a try ... catch if it is possible that the map does not contain the item you search for.

Comment: @KaizerSozay I was adding that to the answer as you were asking